# Setting array variable to null does not trigger change in child components

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to update a array variable in parent component. There is a case where it needs to be set to null. But that does not trigger changes in the child components, it uses the old values (Checked using ngOnChange).

Parent.compoent.ts

```js
function someFunc(){
    this.arrayVar = someCondition ? null : [1,2,3];
}
```

`arrayVar` is used as a property in child component.

I tried using a empty array instaed of null. It worked.

```
function someFunc(){
    this.arrayVar = someCondition ? [] : [1,2,3];
}
```

Why did empty array work but not null.

Comment: Please reproduce this on stackblitz or codesandbox and post the link here. It's hard to determine what went wrong with your code.

Comment: Nothing to do with angular, this is js understanding issue

Answer (score 0):

When you set arrayVar to [], meaning you change its reference and it triggers the change detection but when you set arrayVar to null, Angular might not immediately recognize it as a change in the reference. To fix it, try adding a manual change detection trigger with cdr.detectChanges()

Answer (score -1):

In JS we have concept of *Truthy & Falsy* for non-boolean variables to coerce them to a boolean, to be more clear, everything that's not belong to falsy will assume to be truthy.

The specific list of "falsy" values in JS is as follow:

- " "(empty string)
- 0, -0, NaN(invalid number)
- null, undefined
- false

so as you can see empty array [ ] and empty object { } will not consider falsy so they will coerced to *true*. therefore null and empty list have different meanings in JS.
Finally because you want to check if the array is empty or not you should use [ ] instead of null cause *empty array will never be equal to null*.